# DocuSign ISV app authentication questions

Tags: docusignapi

So if I have an app with many users on board, all from different companies/places, I'm thinking that an individual 'connect to docusign' with OAuth is the right flow.

I think I could have an admin connect their account and impersonate the entire company, but it doesn't sound great from a security perspective.

I also see some places asking people for their docusign admin username/password which I assume is highly discouraged.

Question: I am planning on using just one 'integration' for my app to manage all this, should I be aiming to use one integration per docusign account I interact with? i.e. Should I ask the companies to each make an integration and give me the id/secret?

Answer (score 0):

Several questions here:

### OAuth flow

Yes, if your DocuSign users will have their own DocuSign user IDs then you can add a "Connect to DocuSign" button and use the OAuth Authorization Code grant flow. Include the `extended` scope so you can use the refresh token on an ongoing basis. Remember to use secure non-volatile storage for the refresh tokens since they can be used to obtain access tokens.

See [Authentication for ISVs](https://developers.docusign.com/partner/integration-guide/auth/)

### I think I could have an admin connect their account and impersonate the entire company, but it doesn't sound great from a security perspective.

Correct. It is best to use JWT grant (impersonation) **only** if the end users can't use the Authorization Code grant flow. For example, if your app is a back-end app or doesn't have a web interface.

JWT (impersonation) flow is fine when needed, but it incurs significant customer confusion and work to provide consent. So Authorization Code grant is preferred if it fits your needs as an ISV.

### One DocuSign client_id (integration key) or one per end-customer?

Best is to use one DocuSign client_id (integration key) for your application, not one per customer. See [ISV docs](https://developers.docusign.com/partner/integration-guide/key-management/)

### Should I ask customers to give me an integration key and secret that they created?

Please no. Your customers are not developers. Asking them to become DocuSign developers and create a client id (integration key) is a lot of work for them. There's no need to go down this path. Just use the same OAuth Authorization Code grant `redirect_uri` for all of your customers. Remember that you can use the `state` parameter as needed to handle the OAuth redirect from DocuSign.

Use your free partner account to `manage` your application's client id and its settings.

### asking for a DocuSign administrator name/pw from your customers

Correct: don't do that!

### you want your customers to set up their DocuSign accounts in a specific way

Your app can do that for them by having including a "Setup DocuSign account" button. That button (when used by an authenticated DocuSign admin) would update the account settings as your app needs. For example, setting up a Connect

### users have multiple accounts

Extra: remember that it is common for DocuSign customers to have access to multiple DocuSign accounts. Eg, a general account, an account for HR, etc. They may or may not set up a special account for your application, depending on the use case.

After a user authenticates, your app can either use the user's default account, or if your application uses a dedicated account, check that the user has a access to it.